# How to format shell output in HTML table

Tags: php, shell, format, output

I am trying to display the following shell commands' output on a webpage: 'df -h' and 'ps au' in a HTML table.

I have found several solutions on Stackoverflow and Google (using awk, column etc..) but none of them take into account that a resulting cell of the output table contains a space. Since there can be a whitespace in a cell and between two columns, I don't know how to properly split the output in columns and populate an HTML table.

For example, with the 'df -h' command I get a 'map -hosts' under Filesystem. At the moment this space is seen as a column delimiter and shifts all other columns in the HTML table.

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   233Gi   23Gi  210Gi    10% 6022722 55046718   10%   /
devfs          184Ki  184Ki    0Bi   100%     635        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0        0  100%   /home
```

'ps au' command output (Note the command column that has several whitespaces)

```
USER      PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
Bob  1943   0.0  0.0  2433436   1556 s000  S+    9:56AM   0:00.03 -bash
root     1941   0.0  0.1  2487048   4912 s000  Ss    9:56AM   0:00.03 login -pf Bob
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is a pretty tough problem. You can't even use the column headers as indicator (e.g. "Capacity" is not aligned). You'd pretty much have to use heuristics to parse this properly, which may be too broad and complex to give a complete answer to here. Why not simply output it as `<pre>`?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, you can get a nice formatted output just using tag <pre>.
Oh sorry, already said

Comment: Thanks for your time! I guess it will just have to be a simple <pre> then.